# C3P0 settings impact on Thread.sleep() method

Tags: hibernate, transactions, threadpool, c3p0, thread-sleep

I have set c3PO settings as follows

```
hibernate.c3p0.min_size = "20";
hibernate.c3p0.max_size = "30";
hibernate.c3p0.maxConnectionAge = "10";
hibernate.c3p0.timeout = "15";
```

Then I have my code as follows

```
@Transactional
void m1(){
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        fetch(); // fetches db entry
        Thread.sleep(20000);
        update(); // updates db entries
     }
}
```

Here, I have made thread to sleep for 20 seconds (> maxConnectionAge and timeout). Then the code executes successfully ***without any db connection closed***. Why is it so?

Can someone help me in understanding

1. Does only a single thread get executed for a transaction?
      If so, why are we not getting any db timeout issue?
2. What all C3P0 parameters/DB parameters result in ***db connection got closed?***. Also, does @Transactional play a role for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

When a Connection is checked out, in general, c3p0 does not mess with it. It is in clients' hands. You can sleep a million years, c3p0 won't `close()` that `Connection` until it is checked back into c3p0's control.

There is one major exception to this rule that c3p0 doesn't mess with a checked out `Connection` -- the c3p0 setting [unreturnedConnectionTimeout](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#unreturnedConnectionTimeout). That is [intended specifically](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_to_debug_and_workaround_broken_clients) to workaround and/or debug client applications that have `Connection` leaks. Perhaps that is the setting you are looking for.

In general, c3p0 manages the lifecycle of physical `Connections`, according to your settings. `maxConnectionAge`, `maxIdleTime`, `maxIdleTimeExcessConnections`, connection testing settings and test results can all cause physical connections to be `close()`ed *when they are in the custody of the pool, not the client*. Clients are responsible for `close()`ing the connections they check out (which in fact does not destroy the physical `Connection` but instead returns it to the pool).